# Why does Spring complain about WebApplicationContext only after adding a tld

Tags: apache, spring, tags

When I add this tld and custom tag to my jsp Spring throws an error on startup.  The page 'index.jsp' that is loading is configured as the default first page for the application.  Please explain why this is happening?  Everything works as expected before the tag is added to the page.

head.tag

```
<%@ attribute name="title" required="true" description="Page's title" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="../mytags.tld" prefix="pbl" %>
<head>
<title>
<spring:message code="${title}" text="${title}"></spring:message>
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/global.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" media="screen" />
<jsp:doBody />
</head>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/mytags.tld" prefix="pbl" %>
<html>
    <pbl:head title="hello">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/global.css" media="screen" />
    </pbl:head>
<body>
    <a href="home">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

1: <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/mytags.tld" prefix="pbl" %>
2: <html>
3: <pbl:head title="hello">
4:  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/global.css" media="screen" />
5: </pbl:head>
6: <body>

root cause 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:84)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:81)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:219)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:76)
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.head_tag._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(head_tag.java:132)
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.head_tag.doTag(head_tag.java:85)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_pbl_005fhead_005f0(index_jsp.java:93)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because spring tags expect a spring application. To have such, you need to define a `ContextLoaderListener` as `<listener>..</listener>` in web.xml (I suspect thta mapping a `DispatcherServlet` should also be fine, although not indicated by the message)

Comment: That does seem to get rid of the ContextLoaderListener problem, but causes an issue with finding my annotated controller mappings.  I get a 404 error for all mappings.

Comment: @coder that's a different problem (and hence a different question). You obviously didn't setup your application properly. Check the petclinic example application to see what you should configure where.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My issue was that I was missing a <context:component-scan> which is required when you have a listener to tell Spring where to scan for my files.